Vapor barrier underneath hardwood floor?
I am building a 30x46 pole barn with a subfloor (white oak hardwood on top of the Plywood with tar paper in between ). The floor is 8 ft off the ground in which underneath is dry and open to the outside and will be used for storage of my tractor. The barn will be insulated as we will use a minisplit when it gets too hot/cold. My question, do I need a vapor barrier under the Plywood or would that not allow moisture to escape the floor?

That's an awful nice floor for a tractor.
